# What could be the cause for strange size(s) of TorBrowser window?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, fingerprinting

I tested my TorBrowser with websites like panopticlick. Then downloaded and installed a 2nd TorBrowser to test against.

**a)** the window size is supposed to be a multiple of 100. but I get slightly different values.

**b)** the two browsers don't return the same window size - they aren't identical.

TB1: 1004x820

TB2: 1004x801

(one website reports back 988 instead of 1004, and obviously both browsers are running on the same hardware and display)

Any ideas what is going on here?
How can my TB become identical to others again?